# Reuters Dataset Labels description

Tags: nlp, dataset

the list of Reuters dataset labels are provided with the dataset and also available in varous online resources. [Here is an example.](https://martin-thoma.com/nlp-reuters/)

But I couldn't find what each of these labels actually means.
I was able to find out 'acq' is short for 'Acquisitions'. But yet don't know these ones:
**dlr, gnp, bop**

Is there a description availbale about what these labels represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [the paper introducing the dataset](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/lewis04a/lewis04a.pdf) mentions a list of "online appendices" (table 1 p 363) which seems to contain details about the categories. However I wasn't able to find these appendices in the [additional material](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/lewis04a/).

---

[edit] Since it appears that there is no existing source for the original list of topics, I think your best bet is to rely on an acronym dictionary. Based on [Acronym Finder](https://www.acronymfinder.com), given that the data is mostly about economic news, I think the most likely meaning for the three topics you mention are:

- DLR: dollar
- GDP: Gross Domestic Product
- BOP: Balance Of Payments

You could check whether these are correct by looking at a few documents labelled with these topics in the dataset.

Comment: I think I found the appendix that you are talking about. [It's here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjf1aKi99LsAhWJg3IEHXepBngQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2Fbbm%253A978-3-642-04533-2%252F1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw17-VnQeOsnuueVpsnOx42C ). But it's not talking about these labels.

Comment: @FatemehRahimi you were better than me at finding these appendices! it's a shame, I was hoping the details would be in the appendices as it's usually the case. from the details of the history of the dataset (appendix A.2) it looks like the topics annotations were made even earlier in 1987 but it looks like this was not made public at the time.

Comment: @FatemehRahimi had another idea, see edit.